# How to disable click event while processing ajax form or for 2 seconds via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know this question has been asked 100 times, but nothing is working for me.

1.) I do not want to use css option (which only disable button click from cursor)

2.) `off.()` event permentaly disable the click event (or i don't know, how to use it)

3.) `prop("disable", true)` function is not working in my case.

Here is my code:

```
$(".fa-thumbs-up").click(function( event ) {
// Stop form from submitting normally
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get some values from elements on the page:
    var $form = $(".like-button-form"),
    data = $form.serialize(),
    url = $form.attr( "action" );

    // Send the data using post
    var posting = $.post( url, data );

    // Put the results in a div
    posting.done(function( data ) {
    response = JSON.parse(data);
    $(form).children("input[name='likedornot']").attr("value",response.likedornot); 
    });    

});
```

HTML

```
<form class=".like-button-form" action="sdfs.php" method="POST">
<i class="fa-thumbs-up"></i>
</form>
```

Comment: On a general note. You don't want to catch the `click` even on a button in a form. You always want to catch the `submit` event of the form itself.

Comment: I don't have a `<input type="submit" />` button, my button is `<i class="fa-thumbs-up" ></i>`

Comment: see my updated code, sorry for missing it out. @Tomalak

Comment: and where is `input[name='likedornot']`

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef it is inside formm, but unneccesory to the question, so i did not mention it

Comment: So there is no real form there anyway, just an `<i>` with a `click` action? What's the point of having a `<form>` element, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var submitForm = function( event ) {
    // Stop form from submitting normally
    $(event.target).off('click');
    event.preventDefault();
    enter code here
    // Get some values from elements on the page:
    var $form = $(".like-button-form"),
    data = $form.serialize(),
    url = $form.attr( "action" );

    // Send the data using post
    var posting = $.post( url, data );

    // Put the results in a div
    posting.done(function( data ) {
        response = JSON.parse(data);
        $(form).children("input[name='likedornot']").attr("value",response.likedornot); 
        $(event.target).one('click',submitForm);
    });    

}

$(".fa-thumbs-up").one('click',submitForm);
```

Made slight change to your function to use off and on the event.

If you want to do the same for 2 seconds, use the below method:

```
var submitForm = function( event ) {
// Stop form from submitting normally
        $(event.target).off('click');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(event.target).one('click',submitForm);
    },2000)
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get some values from elements on the page:
    var $form = $(".like-button-form"),
    data = $form.serialize(),
    url = $form.attr( "action" );

    // Send the data using post
    var posting = $.post( url, data );

    // Put the results in a div
    posting.done(function( data ) {
        response = JSON.parse(data);
                            $(form).children("input[name='likedornot']").attr("value",response.likedornot); 
    });    

}

$(".fa-thumbs-up").one('click',submitForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this no need to use form or input .. its enough to use `data` attribute and with a little work with `add/removeClass` you'll be done

**Next snippet to test the code** working correctly or not by using `setTimeout()` the click stops and you've to wait 3 second after click

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click' , 'i.fa.fa-thumbs-up:not(.inprogress)' , function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var ThisThumb = $(this),
        GetUrl = ThisThumb.attr('href'),
        LikedOrNot = ThisThumb.hasClass('liked') ? '' : 'liked';
        data = {likedornot : LikedOrNot}; // in sdfs.php use $_POST['likedornot']
    ThisThumb.addClass('inprogress');
    setTimeout(function(){
      ThisThumb.removeClass('liked inprogress').addClass(LikedOrNot);
    } , 3000);
  });
});
```

```css
i.fa.fa-thumbs-up{
  color : #333;
  font-size : 30px;
}
i.fa.fa-thumbs-up.inprogress{
  color : #ccc;
}
i.fa.fa-thumbs-up.liked{
  color : blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">


<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" data-action="sdfs.php"></i>
```

**The code after added ajax to it**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click' , 'i.fa.fa-thumbs-up:not(.inprogress)' , function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var ThisThumb = $(this),
        GetUrl = ThisThumb.attr('href'),
        LikedOrNot = ThisThumb.hasClass('liked') ? '' : 'liked';
        data = {likedornot : LikedOrNot}; // in sdfs.php use $_POST['likedornot']
    ThisThumb.addClass('inprogress');
    var posting = $.post( GetUrl, data );
    posting.done(function(data){
     ThisThumb.removeClass('liked inprogress').addClass(LikedOrNot);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
i.fa.fa-thumbs-up{
  color : #333;
  font-size : 30px;
}
i.fa.fa-thumbs-up.inprogress{
  color : #ccc;
}
i.fa.fa-thumbs-up.liked{
  color : blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">


<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" data-action="sdfs.php"></i>
```

Comment: `positng` there's a typo

Comment: There's an actual Ajax request going on in the OP's code. I don't really see why you have used `setTimeout()` here...?

Comment: @Tomalak this is just to test the code .. and it works perfect before add ajax to it .. and the hidden snippet for complete code with ajax

Comment: Ah, got it. I didn't see that.